# Define Status depending on Criteria

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have advanced Excel/Google Sheets skills. I have more of a conceptual question. I am happy with any solution (Excel or for Sheets, no difference for me).

I have a sheet where various coworkers have access and work with. It is used to define which product needs to go through which steps. Then when a part of a job is done, the status of the product is changed depending on criteria.

You can also think of it as projects and the status of a project.

[image]

The 3 examples shows how the data is input by the workers. Sometimes, the "No" cells are empty, sometimes they have a "No", sometimes for the same product, one criterion is empty, the other has a "No".

If I do a nested IF formula, I would have to create 32 of them (I believe, since its 5 criteria with each 2 options).

Obviously I can do that. I was wondering anyone has a better solution for me? Something more practical.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not sure how should look like your desired output, tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Thanks to all for your help, I ended up firstly, creating ALL scenarios. This was actually the most complex part. See https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/654871-how-generate-all-possible-combinations-two-lists-without-macro.html (Answer from "Tusharm") where I had to repeat this process 5 times to have all possible outcomes. In the end, there were 192 combinations.

Then, I assigned a status for each combination.

Finally, for each product/row, I created another column where I concatenated the different criteria so that it looks exactly like my above combinations. Then finally index match the concatenated criteria to my combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data you've provided, it looks like your statuses are based on the number of Yes's in the input columns.  Also you don't have a status shown for zero Yes's so I'll make an additional for that.

Given that assumption you can use a combination of the `COUNTIF` function (to count the Yes's), and the `IFS` function (to manage nested Ifs better) to drastically reduce the size of your function.

To make this cleaner I suggest you add a column and hide it containing: `=COUNTIF([InputCriteria1to5Range],"Yes")`

For the next formula assume the formula above is in B2.  In your status column put the following:
`=IFS(B2=5, Status1, B2=4, Status2, B2=3, Status3, B2=2, Status4, B2=1, Status5, B2=0, Status6)`

Comment: If you wanted to be even fancier you could have a lookup table with the number of Yes's and the corresponding status.  Then just do a `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX`+`MATCH` on it.  This would be a more elegant solution because then if you ever need to modify a status or add a new one, you only need to do it in one place!